# Code doesnt work with infinite lists

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on function which takes 2 integers and a list as arguments and returns a list with the elements of the first list which are at the positions between these 2 integers (function :: Int->Int->[u]->[u]). For example:

```
>function 2 5 [1..10]
```

returns

```
[2,3,4,5]
```

The above example is working with my current code...but if I insert an infinite list like [0..] it returns an "ERROR - Garbage collection fails to reclaim sufficient space". Any suggestions? 
Here is the code

```
function :: Int->Int->[u]->[u]                                                       
function i j s
    |i<0 = function 0 j s
    |j< length s = function i j (init s) 
    |j-i< (length s)-1 = function i j (tail s)
    |otherwise = s
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know where your implementation goes wrong when you don't post its source code?

Comment: You are right, post edited. I didnt post the code because I didnt write something to handle infinite lists...

Comment: `function` is a little weird; we usually index lists starting at `0` in Haskell rather than starting at `1`. That said, you can easily define it in terms of prelude functions `drop` and `take` which both operate correctly on infinite lists. `function start end = drop (start - 1) . take end`.

Comment: @Cirdec Almost, but in that case the example would be ``[2,3,4,5,6]`` if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is the use of `length`. Using `length` with an infinite list as parameter is not a good idea because, well, the list in infinitely long.

I would suggest altering the implementation to use other functions which can work on infinite lists, such as `drop` and `take`:

```
function :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
function i j list = take (i - j + 1) (drop (i - 1) list)
```

Or, pointfree:

```
function i j = take (j - i + 1) . drop (i - 1)
```

Comment: A function with the type `Int->Int->[u]->[u]` can't be "searching" for its arguments in the list, since there's no way to compare a `u` to an `Int`. The integer arguments are described as being "positions" or indexes into the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the code works but it couldnt handle a negative input. I added this and its okay now : 
`|i<0 = function 0 j list
|otherwise = take (j - i + 1) (drop (i - 1) list)`

Answer (score 1):

How about: the length of an infinite list?
I think that is not possible.

Comment: Of course, an infinite list doesn't have length. I already knew that my code wouldnt work for infinite lists. I just wanted to know a way to handle an infinite list as an input and return a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

An approach based in zipping with indexes and filtering out those not within the given range,

```
f :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
f i j = map (snd) . filter (\v -> fst v `elem` [i..j]) . zip [1..]
```